# Wrong UIMenu for cell after collection view reload

Tags: ios, swift, cell, collectionview, uimenucontroller

I'm having issues with a `UIMenu` attached to the UIButton for a cell. So the `UIMenu` on a button (button is part of a cell) in a collection view, and if while `UIMenu` is presented there’s a `collectionView.reloadData()` then `UIMenu` changes position AND is transferred to another cell, using new cell data for actions.
So it seems that after `reloadData()`, `UIMenu` is using the cell/data not of the primarily selected cell.

Here’s the code I’m using: https://pastebin.com/wuNsPki5

How to test what issue I have:

1. Run app
2. Tap on any cell
3. Wait 10 seconds
4. Tap share action
5. Output says it shared another value than it was expected

```
UIAction(title: "Share") { [weak self] _ in
    guard let self else { return }
    print("Share \(self.value)")
}
```

So if I tapped on second cell (value == 1), wait 10 seconds (trigger `collectionView.reloadData`) and then tap Share Action, I'd expect that it will print "Share 1", but it actually prints "Share 3" for example.

Comment: The only solution I see for now is to override `prepareForReuse` and set `moreButton.menu = nil`, so that on collection view reload we actually hide the menu and the user will have to reopen the menu and it will be opened with the correct values.

But I'm also interested if there's any way to fix it so that the menu is still displayed and the action is using the right values.

Comment: Assuming you are reloading the data because *the data may have changed* ... do you want the tap on the menu to reflect the data that ***was*** in the cell? or the data that is ***now*** in the cell?

Comment: That was in the cell, because 99% of the time the cell data remains the same at the same position, so now thinking about that maybe `reloadData()` is a bad approach, and I should try to use diffable data source to insert new items and update old ones, instead of reloading whole collection view.

Comment: Seems a little odd to tap on a cell that is displaying "2" (for example)... show a "share" menu... reload the data while the menu is open, changing the "2" to "7"... and then the user taps "share" and it shares "2"? You may be better off having the tap *tell the controller* to display a menu that would have the `value` from the cell at the time of the tap.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate ideas:

1. Simply don't reloadData() while the menu is up.  I mean, that is pulling the rug out from under the menu and the button it's attached to, so to speak.
2. When the user taps the button in the UICollectionView cell, have it trigger an invisible button's UIMenu that lives outside of the collection view, atop it.  Then the collection view can reload its data all it wants while the menu is up.  Now if cells are added or removed, the tail of the UIMenu may not be in the right place anymore, but you wouldn't want to move the UIMenu around while it's being shown anyways as that'd be trouble for the user.

I've never tried either of these approaches, but it's what I'd explore if in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case not reloading data is not an option, but the second approach seems interesting, thank you for your ideas. For now, I decided to move forward with the approach of dismissing the UIMenu.